# Find an Anchor tag inside a Paragraph tag.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup which I need to bind a click event to the `<a>` tag below.

How can i achieve this?

```
         <p class="people_rt_link2" id="test">
        <a href="#" title="2011">2011</a>
        <p style="padding-left: 3px; margin: 3px 0px;">
        a href="http://192.168.20.24/mclarengroup/archives/928">McLaren to build £10m Big Yellow in Chiswick, West London</a>
            </p>
            <br>
           <a href="#" title="2010">2010</a>
          <br>
    </p>
```

This is my current javascript function:

```
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                      $(document).ready(function() {

                          $('.people_rt_link2 a').click(function() {
                                alert('aa');
                          });

                          var data = { cat_id:<?php echo $cat_id?>,posted_year:<?php echo $posted_year?>};
                          jQuery.post("<?php echo $ajax_page_details->guid?>", data, function(response) {
                            $('#test').html(response);
                          });
                      });
                    </script>
```

Comment: If the jquery post which works on page load is removed.The code works.What am i missing here?

Comment: There is already a click bound to a in your question. The javascript from the post might not be correct and might prevent the click function to be activated.

Comment: Your html is badly formed. No leading open angle bracket at " a href="http://192.168.20.24"

Comment: Also not that a p(aragraph) inside a p(aragraph) is not recommended.

Comment: As what jeffreydev said, you should not use a `<p>` within another `<p>`. Instead, change that inner `<p>` to a `<span>` and apply styling to it as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could possible do it by setting an id for the link.

HTML:

```
 <a href="" id="link123">123</a>
```

Javascript:

```
 $("#link123").click(...);
```

Have a look at the jquery documantation specially for selectors:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Yes..i knew that p inside p is poorly formatted.

My issue was not just that bind the click,but when a jquery load was there i can't find the element.

Solved using writing a onclick for a..

Answer (score 0):

You HTML is poorly formed. If you want those styles, apply them directly to the element itself  (as shown) or wrap it in a span rather than another paragraph tag.

I also opened an `<a>` tag for you and self closed your `</br>`

http://jsfiddle.net/pSGRE/